# Bootstrap share url container

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have an app that generates a URL that needs to be shared. I'm trying to find the right container for displaying the generated URL with bootstrap 4.

I want it to look and behave something like google drive shareable link (on the picture below):
[image]

When you click inside it, it selects all text within and makes it easy to copy it. Is there a bootstrap component for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can customize the copy function in javascript

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
</script>
```

, and then set the styling with Bootstrap 4.